# How can I catch an application crash or exit in mshtml?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

Our application is using mshtml. That dll is causing our application to exit ungracefully due to well known problems in mshtml since we don't install newer browsers on users' machines. We just use what they have already.

The `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` does not handle this, nor does a `try`/`catch` block around the calls into mshtml.  The exception filter does catch other exceptions.

The exception settings are `/EHa`.

When I remote debug the crash I see:

> unhandled exception - access violation

In mshtml but if I don't attach to the process with a debugger, the application just exits.

What do we need to do to catch the exception?

---

#### Edit:

This is an old version of IE6.

Comment: I don't know of *well known problems in MSHTML* could it be that you're misusing it? (e.g. passing the wrong parameters, not using marshaled pointers). Please either provide a reference to the *well known problems* or try to give a more specific description.

Comment: We've noticed this also in our application. Many customers have not installed the latest patches (some have never installed _any_ patches). Others have plugins - even locally-developed plugins - which are buggy. MSHTML of certain vintages will also _give up_ rendering some larger pages.

Comment: @Motti
The problem happens with badly formed html pages - but that should not crash mshtml and our app.  (This app hosts ads and we aren't responsible for the content.  Note also that newer versions of mshtml don't crash (I think IE6 is the version we are seeing the issue with)

Comment: @motti:
If you prefer, replace "well known"  with "Lots and lots".  Try this google search.  

 http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=crash+in+mshtml&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g-p2&fp=Xmf0jJ9P_V0

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be that MSHTML functions passes necessary data to a separate thread. That separate thread processes your request and the exception takes place. That's why you cannot catch exception via try/catch block. You should check it in the debugger. If that is true the only way to catch exceptions from other threads is to set hooks for `TerminateThread` and `TerminateProcess` functions. Check out `CApiHook` class by Jeffrey Richter for that purpose(or other implementations). But it will make your program to be incompatible with `/NXCOMPAT` compiler flag.

Your second option is to install all important OS updates.

Comment: Thanks - we'll look at that - and yes, it would be nice to require/install latest IE and other stuff, but that is not really possible right now.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. It's not `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` but `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` you want. With that said, you can get the first shot at this exception.

Of course I'm wondering what you're going to do afterwards. TerminateThread is probably the only option you have, but that may very well deadlock MSHTML. So that needs killing too.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering what I am going to do about it as well...  Right now I just want to take a look at what is actually happening.